# What's the meaning of __typeof keyword in Objective-C context?

Tags: objective-c, typeof

What's the meaning of `__typeof` keyword in Objective-C context?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `__typeof` keyword has the same meaning as [the `typeof` keyword](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Typeof.html): it is used at compile-time instead of an explicit type, to mean the type of its parameter.

You will see `__typeof` in system header files because the `typeof` keyword is non-standard.  So the `typeof` keyword can be disabled by a compiler flag, or the user can `#define` it to mean something else.  The C language standard reserves all identifiers that start with `__` for use by the compiler, so the compiler can define the `__typeof` keyword even when the `typeof` keyword is disabled, and the user is not supposed to `#define` it to mean something else.

Comment: Can you give a link about `typeof` manual

Comment: I have edited it into the answer.